# How can Mysql Query Acceleration

Tags: mysql

How can I make this query faster. Currently in 4ms. It works very slowly.
SELECT  oe.hareket down to 0.2 seconds. How can I optimize it. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT
  og.ogrenciId,
  og.adSoyad,
  eo.istikamet,`enter code here`
  (
    SELECT
      oe.hareket
    FROM
      ogrencietkinlik oe
    WHERE
      oe.istikamet = 1
      AND oe.ogrenciId = eo.ogrenciId
      and oe.zaman BETWEEN "2019-02-15 00:00:00"
      AND "2019-02-1523:59:59"
    ORDER BY
      oe.ogrencietkinlikId DESC
    LIMIT
      0, 1
  ) as hareket,
  (
    SELECT
      oadr.lat
    FROM
      ogrenciadres oadr
    WHERE
      og.ogrenciId = oadr.ogrenciId
    ORDER BY
      oadr.ogrenciadresId DESC
    LIMIT
      0, 1
  ) as lat,
  (
    SELECT
      oadr.lng
    FROM
      ogrenciadres oadr
    WHERE
      og.ogrenciId = oadr.ogrenciId
    ORDER BY
      oadr.ogrenciadresId DESC
    LIMIT
      0, 1
  ) as lng,
  (
    SELECT
      oadr.acikAdres
    FROM
      ogrenciadres oadr
    WHERE
      og.ogrenciId = oadr.ogrenciId
    ORDER BY
      oadr.ogrenciadresId DESC
    LIMIT
      0, 1
  ) as acikAdres
FROM
  ogrenci og
  LEFT JOIN eslestirmeservisogrenci eo ON eo.ogrenciId = og.ogrenciId
  AND eo.servisId = "5"
WHERE
  og.okulId = "4"
  and og.firmaId = "2"
  and og.durum = 0
  and eo.firmaId = "2"
  and eo.durum = 0
ORDER BY
  eo.sira ASC
```

Comment: Have a look at using [joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/join.html) instead of adding multiple select statements into one query

Comment: You always use `ORDER BY` in your sub selects. I see, why they might be neccessary, but these might be the cause of the performance issue. If you cannot query without, you should think about some restructuring

Comment: "You always use ORDER BY in your sub selects. I see, why they might be neccessary, but these might be the cause of the performance issue. If you cannot query without" @yunzen the `ORDER BY` is needed in combination with `LIMIT`.. Because SQL is by definition **orderless** meaning using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is **meaningless**.in SQL.

Comment: Of couse, but it will slow the query down.

Comment: "Of couse, but it will slow the query down" @yunzen if you don't you can get invalid records as "first" record because SQL does not guarantee the order without using `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Yes, yes, all of this is true.

Comment: "Yes, yes, all of this is true." @yunzen besides you can't compare performance between a query which give correct data always and a query which gives you the correct results maybe by chance.

Comment: I can't get the last value without  ORDER BY . Is there a solution proposal?

Comment: "Is there a solution proposal?" read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)